# iPhone: Can another app overwrite my sqlite database?

Tags: iphone

This is a very dumb question, I'm sure. But is it possible for another app to overwrite your database if they used the exact database name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Your app is in the sandbox that other apps can not access. At least on non-jailbroken device.

[iOS Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html)

> **The Application Sandbox**
>
> For security reasons, iOS restricts each application (including its
>   preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This
>   restriction is part of the security feature known as the application’s
>   sandbox. The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an
>   application’s access to files, preferences, network resources,
>   hardware, and so on. Each application has access to the contents of
>   its own sandbox but cannot access other applications’ sandboxes.